# Explain the meaning of 'endogenous' as used in this contex: "policing and crime are endogenous to unobservable strategic interaction"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From a recent LA Times article (https://www.latimes.com/science/sciencenow/la-sci-sn-proactive-policing-crime-20170925-story.html), full quote below, italics mine:

> Simultaneously, citizens decide to comply with the law or commit crime partly on the basis of police deployment and enforcement strategies. In other words, policing and crime are *endogenous* to unobservable strategic interaction, which frustrates causal analysis.

I am struggling to understand these sentences, a quick dictionary search for endogenous gives "caused by factors inside the organism or system" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endogenous), but I cannot figure out how to interpret 'endogenous to' in the context above.

Comment: It means that policing and crime affect each other, just to be brief about it.

Comment: It also means the author probably heard or read that word somewhere and decided to deploy it without understanding the actual meaning of the word.  Their attempt at precision had the opposite effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition you provided makes sense to me, even if I find the rest of the sentence somewhat suspect.

To paraphrase the part in question:

> Policing and crime are [internal factors of] unobservable strategic interaction.

Assuming that no mistake was made, then the author is saying that police deployment and enforcement strategies are both things that are observable, but strategic interaction is not something that's observable—and that policies around policing and crime make up and dictate (*endogenously*) this unobservable strategic interaction.

---

However, I find the particular use of terms to be questionable. I would consider *strategic interaction* to be just as visible as *police deployment* and *enforcement strategies*. It would only be the policies behind all of that that could not be observed.

In short, I think the following is what the passage is actually intending to say:

> The hidden policies that make up and dictate the policing of crime are not apparent to the casual observer of visible police-suspect interaction. Many people can't understand why police act as they do in some situations, and so they either follow the law or commit crime purely on the basis of their reactions to what they observe to be happening and on their assumptions about the reasoning behind it.

Comment: This was very clarifying and seems like it could be correct- it also prompted another possible interpretation - if I assume the first sentence is trying to say something like "Simultaneously, citizens decide to comply with the law or commit crime partly on the basis of police deployment and enforcement strategies AND police deployment and enforcement strategies are based partly on the basis of crime levels" then the 'unobservable strategic interaction' is the real-time feedback loop between policing and crime of which we only observe end results i.e. # of police deployed, # of crimes committed

Comment: @Edna Yes, that's possible too. I don't like how ambiguous the passage is in terms of the terminology and phrasing being used. It's difficult to know if the author used it deliberately (but awkwardly), or if an actual mistake was made in some of the wording.

Answer (score 3):

From Lexico:

> **[endogenous](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/endogenous)**: having an internal cause or origin

Let X stand for "unobservable strategic interaction".

As per Lexido, "endogenous to X" means "having an internal cause or origin" in X.

From this it follows that "policing and crime" have an internal cause or origin in X.

That "policing and crime" have an internal cause or origin in X "frustrates causal analysis" because one can't perform a causal analysis based on unobservable interactions.

Fundamentally, the causes and origins of both crime and society's reaction to crime through policing are not "observable" by ordinary citizens, i.e., by those who are neither committing (or considering committing) crimes nor developing and implementing law-enforcement strategies.

Answer (score 2):

I hope the author isn't trying to use *endogenous* the way economists use the word because that would make the statement just plain wrong.  You can't have something endogenous to an "unobservable" anything. By definition, the causal structure must be explicit as far as internal dependencies are concerned. That is basically the point you are making when you  use the word.

> Definition:
> Endogenous variables designates variables in an economic/econometric model that are explained, or predicted, by that model.

https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=794

Comment: Isn't it "ontogeny recapitulates phylogeny"? - But thank you for the definition of its use in econometrics - looking back LA Times is quoting a sociologist, so maybe there is some drift in the usage

Comment: Doh!! I'll delete that bit - thanks.